# Deleting from table using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Seem to be having an error trying to delete a tuble (usernames) from an SQL table using PHP/SQL queries. My current code is as follows:

```
<html lang="en" >
<body>
<?php
        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'myUsername', 'myPassword', 'dbName') or die ('Cannot connect to db');

        $uname=$_POST['uname'];

        $conn->query("DELETE FROM Account WHERE username = $uname");

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'alert("-ADMIN-\nRemoved user successfully!");';
        echo 'window.location.href = "admin.php";';
        echo '</script>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This exact same code works to delete a post from a website from a differnt table but is not deleting user accounts by username. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to prepare and execute this statement for it to work. `$stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM Account WHERE username = ?'); $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['uname']); $stmt->execute();`

Comment: you do not need to prepare it for it to work. OP is just a newbie. though preparing the query ensures sql injection attacks are removed.

Comment: Well if you call opening yourself to an SQL attack - "working", then sure, you can get "working" code by adding single quotes to your query and having raw post data within your SQL.

Answer (score 1):

presumably `$uname` is a string and the column `username` is also a string so you need to quote the variable within the string

```
$conn->query("DELETE FROM Account WHERE username = '$uname'");
```

This does however leave your code open to sql injection so you would be better using a prepared statement

```
$stmt=$conn->prepare("DELETE FROM Account WHERE username = ?" );
$stmt->bind_param('s', $uname );
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Checkout this solution**

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'myUsername', 'myPassword', 'dbName') or die ('Cannot connect to db'); 
 $stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM Account WHERE username = ?');
 $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['uname']); 
 $stmt->execute();
```